# Firefox box shadow inset not working properly

Tags: html, css, firefox, pseudo-element

I'm using box-shadow to create internal "border" on left and right. It works great in Chrome or Edge but in Firefox it creates "bottom border" as well. I tried prefixing with -moz- and -webkit- but unsuccessfully.

I don't know how to simulate it in chrome so please run the code in Firefox to see what I am talking about.

Also, it sometimes glitches when zooming in or out in the browser (But zooming in or out in Firefox didn't fix it)

[image: Chrome box-shadow]
[image: Firefox box-shadow]

```css
div{
      width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #001f49;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 77% 23%;
    align-items: center
}
h1{
  color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:18px;
}
span{
      background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0 0 #001f49, inset 1px 0 0 0 #001f49, inset 0 -1px 0 0 #001f49;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0 0 #001f49, inset 1px 0 0 0 #001f49, inset 0 -1px 0 0 #001f49;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0 0 #001f49, inset 1px 0 0 0 #001f49, inset 0 -1px 0 0 #001f49;
}
span::before{
  background: inherit;
    top: -22px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transform: skewY(352deg);
    transform-origin: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0 0 #001f49, inset 1px 0 0 0 #001f49;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0 0 #001f49, inset 1px 0 0 0 #001f49;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0 0 #001f49, inset 1px 0 0 0 #001f49;
}
a{
  color: #ed174a;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>
Change
</h1>
<span><a href="#">Pricelist</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the whole thing differently using background and less of code:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border:1px solid #001f49;
  background: linear-gradient(-13deg,#0000 33%,#001f49 34%);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 77% 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a {
  color: #ed174a;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    Change
  </h1>
  <span><a href="#">Pricelist</a></span>
</div>
```